# What is right way to send visitors from one webform to other webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

What is right way to send visitors from one webform to other. What are their limitations  and their plus points. Please explain.

Comment: Homework got ya down?

Comment: The 'right way' is going to depend on what you'd like to accomplish, and the design of your app.  Can you elaborate?  Also:  This sounds like it's an attempt to get somebody to do your homework.  If it's not, please state that clearly.

Comment: Oh, and if this is an attempt to get help with homework, please be honest about that, too

Comment: Oh again...make sure youre honest.

Comment: no it is not homework, I am a novice programmer of c# asp.net.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow jams. You'll get better answers faster if you make your question as clear and direct as possible. Read this for some suggestions: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to provide a link, which the user has to click:

```
<a href="Step2.aspx">Next Step</a>
```

This sends the user to step 2 directly, without any opportunity to do anything in between/

Another way is to simply redirect the response:

```
Response.Redirect ("Step2.aspx");
```

This will directly send the user to step 2 and is typically used when some processing needs to be done before going to step 2.

You could also use a meta tag to redirect

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=Step2.aspx">
```

When a delay is required, this is the usual way. The current form simply displays an "accepted" message and then directs to a new page.

Setting the action attribute of the form element is an alternative:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="Step2.aspx">
```

This approach is usually used when the second steps uses some data posted from the first step.

I'm sure there are plenty of other ways, but these are the few common ones that I use.

Answer (score 1):

The big question is what do you mean by "send"?  @Fun Mun Pieng covered redirect, which is the right way to do things if you want to give the user the same experience as if they clicked a link and visited a different webform.

If, however, you want to preserve all of the form values, effectively posting back to a different webform, then you want to look at `Server.Transfer("redirectForm.aspx")`.  The clue to what it's doing different from `Response.Redirect("redirectForm.aspx")` is in the object you're manipulating.  Response.Redirect() is sending an instruction down to the browser, as a response, directing it to lodge a separate request for a different resource.  Server.Transfer() is highjacking the current request and giving control over to a different page without the browser ever knowing about it.  They may seem similar, but this is a HUGE difference...